# Getting MemoryError for a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memcached, aplpy

I am analyzing some fits images using `Aplpy` and the images are read into arrays but I get this error message:

**Update:**

```
    fitsfile=rgb.fits
    aplpy.make_rgb_cube(['R.fits',
                 'V.fits',
                 'U.fits'],fitsfile)

    File "Plot.py", line 48, in <module>
    'image_U_38.fits'],fitsfile)
  File "/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/APLpy-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/aplpy/rgb.py", line 293, in make_rgb_cube

     image_cube = np.zeros((len(files), ny, nx), dtype=np.float32)
MemoryError
```

I wasn't getting this error message before. I assume the memory cache that python is using got full and I need to trash the temporary stuff there. I can not change the content of `Aplpy` library as well.

For more information, I use `python 64 bit`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
>>> 2**64
18446744073709551616L
```

and I also tried the following function to get rid of the error but it didn't help

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you show how you call the `Aplpy` function, give some details of the FITS images you're working with, and could you tell what your system resource monitor says about memory usage at the moment this error occurs? It seems you're simply running out of memory.